# how do i download a file (zip) from the internet in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-express

experts. I'm trying to create a simple file downloader (with GUI). I'm pretty new to Vb.net and I didn't find any usefull information about this in the books I own. All tutorials in the wild are making me more frustrated, since the snippets I use, in most cases, are different classes.
So I have some basic questions:

- What should I use? `HttpWebRequest/HttpWebResponse` or
  `FileWebRequest/FileWebResponse`?
- How do I save the `ResponseStream` to a file ?
- Is it possible to use ResponseStream to define the kind of File (FileInfo) Class to get basic file information (size, extension, etc)

  - is it generally neccessary, if `GetResponse().headers` gives you most
    of this info ?

My code, which sucks, because I do not know how to realize the saving....

```
Private Sub btn_downloader_Click(ByVal sender...) Handles btn_downloader.Click
     'e.g http://codeigniter.com/download.php'
     Dim fileUrl As String = txtBox_url.Text 
     Dim webUri = New Uri(fileUrl)
     Dim wReq As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(webUri)
     Dim wRes As HttpWebResponse = wReq.GetResponse()
     Dim resUri As Uri = wRes.ResponseUri
     'to ckeck if http://codeigniter.com/download.php gives http://codeigniter.com/download_files/reactor/CodeIgniter_2.0.0.zip and it does!'
     Dim resStream As Stream = wRes.GetResponseStream()
```

And now I have to somehow use one of the Stream methods to write the file (at this stage only as a Stream), but do not know how.
I saw this in the tutorials

```
resStream.Read(buffer, offset, count)
```

but I don't know what the buffer is and what it is for. Should I set some static values or any dynamic which deppends on Stream-data ?

Need help!

P.S. Sorry for bad English

Comment: Rather than apologizing for the "bad English," why don't you clean it up as best you can?

Comment: I already did. I have no one who could check my text for spelling or grammar errors. So I post it, because it seems to be ok...at least for me. I apologize, couz I'm pretty sure it isn't 100% right and I've made some errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to do it quickly without a progress bar or anything that tracks download speed, estimated time left, etc. then I would suggest `WebClient.DownloadFileAsync or WebClient.DownloadFile`. You should be able to read the mime type with `WebClient.ResponseHeaders["content-type"]` and then rename the file accordingly.

Comment: I do have a progressbar and of couse i wich i can track speed or at least the amount of downloadED bytes. 
But thnaks for quick replay, I will try you suggestion too.

Comment: Then I would suggest you use HttpWebRequest. There are tons of examples that you can find through google. Dont be afraid to look at c# examples either because your using all the same functions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not complete but may get you in right direction.
'Location is where to save file..

```
Public Function DownloadFile(ByVal URL As String, ByVal Location As String) As Boolean
    Try
        Dim WC As New WebClient
        WC.DownloadFile(URL, Location)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```